# Browser Compatibility (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, compatibility

I'm rewriting the scripts for a site in regular Javascript to speed up the color picker, however if you view it in Firefox and IE, it doesn't work (But it works fine in Chrome). I was just really hoping to get some help with this:

https://www.sinister.ly/index.php

```
<div id="theme_styler">
    <div class="option default" id="red"></div>
    <div class="option" id="green"></div>
    <div class="option" id="blue"></div> 
</div>
```

The specific code that seems to be the problem:

```
var optionalStylesheet = document.getElementsByClassName("stylesheet_optional");
var blueStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_blue");
var greenStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_green");
var storedThemeColor = readCookie('themeColor');
var currentFiconPath;

function changeColor(path) {
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName("ficon");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        all[i].src = all[i].src.replace(/ficons\/((green|blue)\/)?/, 'ficons/' + path + '/');
    }
}
```

This is in the header:

```
// AD JS

document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
  var retnode = [];
  var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cl + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
  }
  return retnode;
}; 

function readCookie(name) {
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
var nameEQ = name + "=";
for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length); //delete spaces
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
}
return null;
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

var optionalStylesheet = document.getElementsByClassName("stylesheet_optional");
var blueStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_blue");
var greenStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_green");
var storedThemeColor = readCookie('themeColor');
var currentFiconPath;

function changeColor(path) {
var all = document.getElementsByClassName("ficon");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        all[i].src = all[i].src.replace(/ficons\/((green|blue)\/)?/, 'ficons/' + path + '/');
    }
}

var gs = document.createElement("link");
gs.type = "text/css";
gs.className = "stylesheet_optional";
gs.id = "stylesheet_blue";
gs.rel = "stylesheet";
gs.title = "mystyle";
gs.href = "images/sinisterly/color_blue.css";

var bs = document.createElement("link");
bs.type = "text/css";
bs.className = "stylesheet_optional";
bs.id = "stylesheet_green";
bs.rel = "stylesheet";
bs.title = "mystyle";
bs.href = "images/sinisterly/color_green.css";

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var links = head.getElementsByTagName("link");
for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++) {
   var href = links[x].href;
    if(href.indexOf('/color_green.css') >0 || href.indexOf('/color_blue.css') >0){
      head.removeChild(links[x]);
   }
}

if (storedThemeColor == "green"){
    head.appendChild(bs);
} else if (storedThemeColor == "blue") {
    head.appendChild(gs);
} 

// End AD JS
```

And this in the footer

```
if (storedThemeColor == null) {
    setCookie('themeColor', 'default', 7);
    currentFiconPath = '';
    return currentFiconPath;
} else if (storedThemeColor != null) {
    if (storedThemeColor == 'default') {
        currentFiconPath = '';
        optionalStylesheet.disabled = true;
        return currentFiconPath;
    } else if (storedThemeColor == 'blue') {
        currentFiconPath = "blue";
        changeColor(currentFiconPath);
        optionalStylesheet.disabled = true;
        blueStylesheet.disabled = false;
        return currentFiconPath;
    } else if (storedThemeColor == 'green') {
        currentFiconPath = "green";
        changeColor(currentFiconPath);
        optionalStylesheet.disabled = true;
        greenStylesheet.disabled = false;
        return currentFiconPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what it's supposed to do, and what's happening instead? And is there any relevant output from the JS consoles?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that just contains the problem code and demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Note, `#` is an operator in CSS selectors that `getElementById()` doesn't really use. The argument should match the `id` attribute value exactly.

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured you'd check it out in the browsers haha. What I mean is it doesn't change the directory for the ficons. It's much easier to explain visually than throw text.

Comment: Look, I'm new to the site, so please stop being so harsh and smart toned. Obviously looking at the "changeColor" function it's for changing the color. So at the top right click between the colors and notice it doesn't change the icons colors. I really appreciate the help, just not the aggression.

Comment: I'm getting errors in the Chrome JS console: "Illegal return statement" on line 1622, and lots of "404 not found" errors.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, I changed that on the live version. Still didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @KevinB That's fine of course, but you'd have to see the problem to be able to fix it I'd say. I'm really just looking to find what code works on Chrome, but not IE/Firefox. And it's directly related to the code that changes the color of the ficons on page load.

Comment: If you provide enough html in the question to recreate the issue, i would be able to recreate it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: The site I linked is a forum software site, and it's not mine. I didn't even build all of it, we were just contracted in to speed up their color picker. I converted it to regular JS and was just trying to figure out why it isn't cross browser. jeez

Comment: As far as I can tell, this function isn't used when clicking on the icons. I set a breakpoint in changeColor, and clicked on the icons. The color scheme changed, but the breakpoint never triggered.

Comment: It looks like this function is only used when setting the color scheme from a cookie when the page loads, not when clicking on the color picker.

Comment: changeColor is only activated when the page is loaded (I updated the code in the OP btw). Like I mentioned, it works great in Chrome so I feel like it's just an incompatible function or something.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function in firefox and in chrome and compare the value of `.src` between chrome and firefox, then compare the result of the regexp replace. Also compare the value of `path`

Comment: I'm seeing the same misbehavior in both Chrome and FF: When I first go to the page, clicking on green or blue changes the color of the nav bar, but not the forum icons. But if I go back to red, then click on green or blue, it changes both of them.

Comment: I think the relevant code is the part that starts with `$('.option').click(function ()`, not the code you posted.

Comment: I fixed it, however it says I can't post the answer for 8 hours after asking the question. Basically I had to remove all the returns/.disable code from the footer section that I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: When `document.getElementById` returns `undefined`, trying to set a property will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var blueStylesheet = document.getElementById("#stylesheet_blue");
var greenStylesheet = document.getElementById("#stylesheet_green");
```

to:

```
var blueStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_blue");
var greenStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet_green");
```

There's no `#` at the beginning of the stylesheet IDs.

I don't know why it's working in Chrome -- when I try it I get `undefined` in Chrome.

Comment: I did that, it didn't fix the problem.